# PDO fetch then targeted object?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I currently have a page where I'm connecting to db via PDO, db, prepare. 
Selecting SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in order to have pagination with the results. 
All of that is good. However, each return is to have a text popup when clicked. Thats where I want to target a particular field of defined row.

Code I have is as follows :

```
    $db = new     PDO('mysql:dbname=###;host=###','###','###');
    $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
    $perPage = isset($_GET['per-page']) && $_GET['per-page'] <= 50 ?(int)$_GET['per-page'] : 8;

    //Positioning
     $start = ($page > 1) ? ($page * $perPage) - $perPage : 0;
   //Query
    $articles = $db->prepare("
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id, comment_caption, comment_sub_caption,comment_title, comment_main, comment_name,
comment_date, comment_url
FROM TABLE_NAME
LIMIT {$start}, {$perPage}
");

    $articles->execute();
    $articles = $articles->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Pages
    $total = $db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()  as total")->fetch()['total'];
    $pages = ceil($total / $perPage);

    //Pagination div

    <div class="pagination">
    <?php for($x = 1; $x <= $pages; $x++): ?>
        <a href="?page=<?php echo $x; ?>&per-page=<?php echo $perPage; ?> "<?php if($page === $x){ echo 'class="selected"'; }?>><?php echo $x ?></a>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</div>
    // Here is the container for the foreach
     <div id="container">
        <?php
        foreach($articles as $article): ?>
              <div class="item small">
                  <div class="module">
                      <div class="article">
                          <div class="item-inner">
                              <a href="<?php echo $article['comment_url']; ?>">
                                  <div class="project-title">
                                      <div class="mid">
                                          <h2><?php echo $article['comment_caption']; ?></h2>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </a>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    // This is the popup that I want to associate with each return
    <div id="test-popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide">

            <blockquote><?php echo $article['comment_main'];
                ?></blockquote>
            <p><i><?php echo $article['comment_name']; ?> - <?php echo $article['comment_date']; ?></i></p>
        </div>
```

In the popup, I want to echo the 'comments_main, comments_name & comments_date' field of the particular instance that is clicked. Here currently, it just echos the first row.

I'm not sure what the best way to go about it is... ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I agree with comments in answer from @Shadow below.  I do however think that, as posed the question is too broad to answer.  You might have better luck reposting or revising the question to show only the HTML source that is output and any CSS/javascript your are currently using to implement the desired "pop-up" experience.  This truly is a front-end UI problem, not a middleware/backend problem as your question is posed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a php-mysql related question, but rather a javascript-html-css related one.

You have 2 options:

1. You output the comments_main, comments_name & comments_date fields to all listed items in a way they are not visible to the users first in the browser. Typically, you could use the anchor element's title property, or html5's data- properties, or even a list of invisible divs. Whenever the user clicks a link, you use javascript to fetch these data for the given comment from your list on the client side (if they are not stored in a list of divs already) and make it appear.
2. You do not output these data to the client, but upon clicking you use an ajax call to retrieve these data from the server via another php page.

For both approach there are lots of tutorials out there with designed boxes (tooltips) and copy-paste javascript, html, and css code.